# Getting exception while trying DatastoreDb.Create on iPhone Device

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios, grpc

I'm trying to create a DB using DatastoreDb.Create() and getting exception while running it on the iPhone device. The code is working fine on the simulator.

Here is what I'm trying to do:

```
private void SaveToDB()
    {
        try
        {
            // Your Google Cloud Platform project ID.
            string projectId = "xam-project";

            //We are storing movies. So this is a Movie kind. 
            string kind = "Country";

            //Create the datastore db
            var db = DatastoreDb.Create(projectId);

            Entity movieEntities = new Entity
            {
                Key = db.CreateKeyFactory(kind).CreateKey($"US"),
                ["CountryCode"] = "NZ",
                ["Name"] = "NewZeland"
            };

            using (var transction = db.BeginTransaction())
            {
                transction.Upsert(movieEntities);
                transction.Commit();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
}
```

I'm getting following exception:

```
{System.ExecutionEngineException: Attempting to JIT compile method '(wrapper native-to-managed) Grpc.Core.Internal.NativeMetadataCredentialsPlugin:NativeMetadataInterceptorHandler (intptr,intptr,intptr,intptr,intptr,int)' while running in aot-only mode. See https://learn.microsoft.com/xamarin/ios/internals/limitations for more information.

 at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Object.__icall_wrapper_mono_delegate_to_ftnptr(object)
at (wrapper managed-to-native) Grpc.Core.Internal.NativeMethods+DllImportsFromStaticLib.grpcsharp_metadata_credentials_create_from_plugin(Grpc.Core.Internal.NativeMetadataInterceptor)
at Grpc.Core.Internal.NativeMetadataCredentialsPlugin..ctor (Grpc.Core.AsyncAuthInterceptor interceptor) [0x0003b] in T:\src\github\grpc\src\csharp\Grpc.Core\Internal\NativeMetadataCredentialsPlugin.cs:47 
at Grpc.Core.MetadataCredentials.ToNativeCredentials () [0x00000] in T:\src\github\grpc\src\csharp\Grpc.Core\CallCredentials.cs:80 
at Grpc.Core.CompositeChannelCredentials.CreateNativeCredentials () [0x00000] in T:\src\github\grpc\src\csharp\Grpc.Core\ChannelCredentials.cs:202 
at Grpc.Core.ChannelCredentials.<.ctor>b__2_0 () [0x00000] in T:\src\github\grpc\src\csharp\Grpc.Core\ChannelCredentials.cs:45 
at System.Lazy`1[T].CreateValue () [0x00081] in <2b439461a53d406abf16d6e5e34ece7f>:0 
at System.Lazy`1[T].LazyInitValue () [0x00080] in <2b439461a53d406abf16d6e5e34ece7f>:0 
at System.Lazy`1[T].get_Value () [0x0003a] in <2b439461a53d406abf16d6e5e34ece7f>:0 
at Grpc.Core.ChannelCredentials.GetNativeCredentials () [0x00000] in T:\src\github\grpc\src\csharp\Grpc.Core\ChannelCredentials.cs:80 
at Grpc.Core.Channel..ctor (System.String target, Grpc.Core.ChannelCredentials credentials, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[T] options) [0x0007e] in T:\src\github\grpc\src\csharp\Grpc.Core\Channel.cs:77 
at Grpc.Core.Channel..ctor (System.String host, System.Int32 port, Grpc.Core.ChannelCredentials credentials, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[T] options) [0x00000] in T:\src\github\grpc\src\csharp\Grpc.Core\Channel.cs:109 
 at Google.Api.Gax.Grpc.ChannelPool.GetChannel (Google.Api.Gax.Grpc.ServiceEndpoint endpoint, Grpc.Core.ChannelCredentials credentials) [0x0003a] in C:\Users\skeet\Test\Projects\gax-dotnet\releasebuild\Google.Api.Gax.Grpc\ChannelPool.cs:127 
at Google.Api.Gax.Grpc.ChannelPool.GetChannel (Google.Api.Gax.Grpc.ServiceEndpoint endpoint) [0x0001d] in C:\Users\skeet\Test\Projects\gax-dotnet\releasebuild\Google.Api.Gax.Grpc\ChannelPool.cs:93 
at Google.Cloud.Datastore.V1.DatastoreClient.Create (Google.Api.Gax.Grpc.ServiceEndpoint endpoint, Google.Cloud.Datastore.V1.DatastoreSettings settings) [0x00000] in C:\Users\jon\Test\Projects\google-cloud-dotnet\releasebuild\apis\Google.Cloud.Datastore.V1\Google.Cloud.Datastore.V1\DatastoreClient.cs:399 
at Google.Cloud.Datastore.V1.DatastoreDb.Create (System.String projectId, System.String namespaceId, Google.Cloud.Datastore.V1.DatastoreClient client) [0x00000] in C:\Users\jon\Test\Projects\google-cloud-dotnet\releasebuild\apis\Google.Cloud.Datastore.V1\Google.Cloud.Datastore.V1\DatastoreDb.cs:84 
at Kudos.ViewController.SaveToDB () [0x0000c] in /Users/sandeepmahajan/Documents/Projects/sury-kudos/SuryKudos/SuryKudos/ViewController.cs:75 }
```

The Exception occur at this line:

```
//Create the datastore db
var db = DatastoreDb.Create(projectId);
```

Much appreciate for any suggestion/workaround for this.

Comment: You can not JIT on a iOS device. Known limitation of how gRPC works : https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues/18178

Comment: @SushiHangover: Any wrokaround for this?

Comment: Read the issue and the links within that thread